# Android, Why color of my foreground image change in openGL ES?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es

In my application I'm using openGL ES.
I want to show two images in the screen. The first acts as backgroung (PNG format, 32 bit, 1280*800) and second one is foreground (PNG format, 32 bit, 64*512).

I can show both image in the screen but i don't know why the color of foreground image is changed!!! the picture of this problem is:
[image]
While, the original color of hand is brown. in the following image i disabled background image, so we see just the hand with its original color in image.
[image]

please guide me what is the problem and why the color is changed?
Thanks a lot

==========
**Update:**

some part of code:

```
@Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(ATEngine.GAME_THREAD_FPS_SLEEP);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        setBackground(gl);
        setHand(gl);

        //All other game drawing will be called here
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); 
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE);
    }
```

and setHand methode is:

```
private void setHand(GL10 gl){ 
         gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); 
         gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
         gl.glPushMatrix(); 
         gl.glScalef(.1f, .7f, 1f); 
         gl.glTranslatef(4.5f, 0f, 0f);

         gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE); 
         gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
         gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  

         hand.draw(gl); 
         gl.glPopMatrix();   
         gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
     }
```

Comment: You are probably using the wrong blend function. What values do you use for blending?

Comment: Thanks dear Romain, I have put some part of code in my post. I think the code is correct but I don't know why it is like this?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in onDrawFrame() function I changed last line with following line. the problem solved :)

```
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

for more information, please see my reference: http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/blending.html

[image]